# How to safely access every n-th element in a container in a succinct way?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Consider an STL container `C` that is forward-iteratable. I need to access every `step` element, starting from `idx`. If `C` is a vector (i.e. has a random-access iterator) I can just use index arithmetic:

```
template <class Container>
void go(const Container& C) {
    for(size_t i = idx; i<C.size(); i+=step) {
        /* do something with C[i] */
    }
}
```

However, if `C` does not support that, e.g. `C` is a list, one needs to rewrite the above solution. A quick attempt would be:

```
template <class Container>
void go(const Container& C) {
    size_t max = C.size();
    size_t i = idx;
    for(auto it = std::next(C.begin(),idx); i < max; i+=step, it+=step) {
        /* do something with *it */
    }
}
```

Not much longer and it works... except that most likely it will trigger the undefined behavior. Both `std::next` and `it+=step` can potentially step way beyond the `C.end()` before `i < max` check is performed.

The solution I am currently using (not shown) is really bloated when compared to the initial for. I have separate check for the first iteration and those that follows. A lot of boilerplate code...

So, **my question is**, can the above pattern be written in a safe, *and succinct* way? Imagine you want to nest these loops 2 or 3 times. You don't want the whole page of code for that!

- The code should be reasonably short
- The code should have no overhead. Doing `std::next(C.begin(), i)` in each iteration over `i` is unnecessairly long, if you can just `std::advance(it, step)` instead.
- The code should benefit from the case when `it` is indeed a random-access iterator when `std::advance` can be performed in constant time.
- `C` is constant. I do not insert, erase or modify `C` within the loop.

Comment: What invalidation rules are you imposing on your container and its iterators?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify it. All operations on it are read-only. I don't erase, resize, insert or otherwise modify C. Consider `C` to be `const`

Comment: You might want to expand your minimal case here a bit more to indicate `const`, and I'd further encourage you to write a simple unit test to validate this. If there's performance concerns, it's time to write a benchmark as well.

Comment: what about `for(auto it = std::next(C.begin(),idx); (i += step) < max + step; it+=step) {`? Bit ugly though.

Comment: You can still create functions (with tag dispatching for randomAccessIterator) for that.

Comment: @Zereges The initializing `std::next(...)` may already be UB if `C.size() < idx`. Also: `it+=step` will still perform *before* the check, so it won't help.

Comment: @CygnusX1 that is UB in your code as well, so I supposed `idx < C.size()`.

Comment: @Zereges Yes, I am aware of UB. I explicitly said that in my code - that's why this short solution that is shown is incorrect. It is there just to show the *intend* of the code.

Comment: How about `for(...;(i+=step) < max && std::advance(it, step))`

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand your requirements here (from your first example with `<`). Always skip the first element, then skip `step` elements, and start there? More generally what are idx and step? Can they be function parameters to clarify your meaning?

Comment: @MarkB I want to access every `C[idx+k*step]` for all natural `k`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might use helper functions:

```
template <typename IT>
IT secure_next(IT it, std::size_t step, IT end, std::input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (it != end && step--) {
        ++it;
    }
    return it;
}


template <typename IT>
IT secure_next(IT it, std::size_t step, IT end, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    return end - it < step ? end : it + step;
}


template <typename IT>
IT secure_next(IT it, std::size_t step, IT end)
{
   return secure_next(it, step, end, typename std::iterator_traits<IT>::iterator_category{});
}
```

And then:

```
for (auto it = secure_next(C.begin(), idx, C.end());
     it != C.end();
     it = secure_next(it, step, C.end()) {
    /* do something with *it */
}
```

Alternatively, with [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/), you could do something like:

```
for (const auto& e : C | ranges::view::drop(idx) | ranges::view::stride(step)) {
    /* do something with e */
}
```

Comment: Ohh my mistake, I'm using the SO app on my phone and didn't realize the for loop's arguments were split into multiple lines.

Answer (score 7):

The comment in the question about the requirements inspired me to implement this in terms of `k * step` instead of some other mechanism controlling the number of iterations over the container.

```
template <class Container>
void go(const Container& C)
{
    const size_t sz = C.size();

    if(idx >= sz) return;

    size_t k_max = (sz - idx) / step + 1;

    size_t k = 0
    for(auto it = std::advance(C.begin(), idx); k < k_max && (std::advance(it, step), true); ++k) {
        /* do something with *it */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to adapt the iterator so that it is safe to advance past the end. Then you can use stock `std::next()`, `std::advance()`, pass it to functions expecting an iterator, and so on. Then the strided iteration can look almost exactly like you want:

```
template<class Container, class Size>
void iterate(const Container& c, Size idx, Size step)
{
    if (unlikely(idx < 0 || step <= 0))
        return;
    bounded_iterator it{begin(c), c};
    for (std::advance(it, idx); it != end(c); std::advance(it, step))
        test(*it);
}
```

This is not dissimilar from the `secure_next()` suggestion. It is a little more flexible, but also more work. The range-v3 solution looks even nicer but may or may not be an option for you.

Boost.Iterator has facilities for adapting iterators like this, and it's also straightforward to do it directly. This is how an incomplete sketch might look for iterators not supporting random access:

```
template<class Iterator, class Sentinel, class Size>
class bounded_iterator
{
public:
    using difference_type   = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type;
    using value_type        = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    using pointer           = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer;
    using reference         = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference;
    using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category;

    template<class Container>
    constexpr explicit bounded_iterator(Iterator begin, const Container& c)
        : begin_{begin}, end_{end(c)}
    {
    }

    constexpr auto& operator++()
    {
        if (begin_ != end_)
            ++begin_;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr reference operator*() const
    {
        return *begin_;
    }

    friend constexpr bool operator!=(const bounded_iterator& i, Sentinel s)
    {
        return i.begin_ != s;
    }

    // and the rest...

private:
    Iterator begin_;
    Sentinel end_;
};

template<class Iterator, class Container>
bounded_iterator(Iterator, const Container&) -> bounded_iterator<Iterator, decltype(end(std::declval<const Container&>())), typename size_type<Container>::type>;
```

And for random access iterators:

```
template<RandomAccessIterator Iterator, class Sentinel, class Size>
class bounded_iterator<Iterator, Sentinel, Size>
{
public:
    using difference_type   = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type;
    using value_type        = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;
    using pointer           = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer;
    using reference         = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference;
    using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category;

    template<class Container>
    constexpr explicit bounded_iterator(Iterator begin, const Container& c)
        : begin_{begin}, size_{std::size(c)}, index_{0}
    {
    }

    constexpr auto& operator+=(difference_type n)
    {
        index_ += n;
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr reference operator*() const
    {
        return begin_[index_];
    }

    friend constexpr bool operator!=(const bounded_iterator& i, Sentinel)
    {
        return i.index_ < i.size_;
    }

    // and the rest...

private:
    const Iterator begin_;
    const Size size_;
    Size index_;
};
```

As an aside, it seems GCC produces slightly better code with this form than with my attempts at something like `secure_next()`. Can its optimizer reason better about indices than pointer arithmetic?

This example is shared also via [gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffgarrett/85d7660e5d54389a277ffc1ff0708e09) and [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/KWo8Kj).